# how to calculate hpc performance rpeak

Tags: performance, hpc

My work operates cluster system with 20 computing nodes.
and I'm having difficulty to calculate peak theoretical performance of this HPC system.

I know the HPC world is using the following formula for node peak theoretical performance:

> Node performance in GFlops = (CPU speed in GHz) x (number of CPU cores) x (CPU instruction per cycle) x (number of CPUs per node)

but I dont get the how to find out (CPU instruction per cycle) of the CPUs. 
here are the model names of the 20 nodes:

1. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
2. Xeon5450 3.00Ghz 4Core *2
3. Xeon5450 3.00Ghz 4Core *2
4. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
5. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
6. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
7. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
8. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
9. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
10. Xeon5460 3.16Ghz 4Core *2
11. Xeon2690 2.90Ghz 8Core *2
12. Xeon2690 2.90Ghz 8Core *2
13. Xeon2690 2.90Ghz 8Core *2
14. Xeon5680 3.33Ghz 6Core *2
15. Xeon5660 2.80Ghz 6Core *2
16. Xeon5660 2.80Ghz 6Core *2
17. Xeon5660 2.80Ghz 6Core *2
18. Xeon5660 2.80Ghz 6Core *2
19. Xeon2680 2.80Ghz 10Core *2
20. Xeon2680 2.80Ghz 10Core *2

I looked up the intel homepage but cant find the information I need.
Can anyone help me to find out (CPU instruction per cycle) and rpeak of the system?

Answer (score 2):

"Instructions per cycle" isn't that relevant to calculate flops, it should be specifically *floating point* instructions per cycle. The number of floating point instructions per cycle is typically lower than the total number of instructions per cycle. Also don't forget about vector size.

For example for Xeon5460 (Penryn-based Xeon) can execute up to 5 instructions per cycle under the right circumstances, but only two of them can be floating point instructions, and they have to be able to go to different ports (for example `addps` and `mulps`, both of which are "worth" 4 operations because they operate on vectors of 4 floats).

Anyway, you can use these numbers, derived from [this table](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf),

- Penryn/Nehalem/Westmere-like, 2 floating point instructions per cycle, vector size 4 (2 for double), so 8 flop/c or 4 dflop/c.
- Sandy and Ivy, 2 floating point operations per cycle, vector size 8 (4 for double), so 16 flop/c or 8 dflop/c.
- Haswell/Broadwell/Skylake, still 2 floating point operations per cycle but they can be FMAs, so 32 flop/c or 16 dflop/c since an FMA counts for two.

There are more differences between that don't show in these calculations (nor in total Flops, so as usual I question how useful that number is). For example, on Skylake there are more types of floating point instruction that you can execute 2 of in a cycle, such as addition, min/max, comparisons, and some conversions. Broadwell and Haswell can only do two additions per cycle by making them part of FMAs, and min/max etc are out of luck there. Division throughput more than doubles from Haswell to Broadwell, hopefully division is rare but this probably matters at least *sometimes*.

You can look up which architecture a processor is based on on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors).

Xeon2690 refers to several very different processors, though they can be differentiated through core count and frequency you should always include the version number, E5-2690 (Sandy) is something completely different than E5-2690 v4 (Broadwell). Based on core count, the ones you listed are Sandy and Ivy.